# pseudorandom numbers generation technique and mathematical induction

Tags: complex-numbers

I have two questions:

1. I am wondering what would be the first $5$ pseudorandom numbers generated by the linear congruential method with modulus $m=7$, multiplier $a=5$, increment $c=2$, and seed $x_0=6$
2. $1^3+3^3+5^3+...+(2n+1)^3+(n+1)^3=?$

Answers

a. $(n+1)^4$

b. $2(n+1)^4$

c. $(n+1)^3(2n^2+4n+1)$

d. $(n+1)^2(2n^2+4n+1)$

So far I have concluded that the answer is d. Am I correct?

Comment: Second question: The "advantage" of those multiple choice test is that you don't have to be 100% sure about correctness. For $n=0$ the sum evaluates to $2$. Which of the candidates evaluates to $2$ for $n=0$?

Comment: Got ya, then the answer would be option b. I was using mathematical induction to solve this. I am so silly.

Comment: @lauren Two different questions regarding very different problems should be asked separately.

Comment: I was asked to wait 20 minutes before posting another question. So I had to post 2 questions in the same cluster :(

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm, which I have just for the first time read on wikipedia, I find very simple to apply

$$x_n = \left(5x_{n-1}+2\right)\ \ \text{mod } 7$$

For example, given $x_0=6$,

$$x_1 =5(6)+2\ \ \text{ mod } 7 = 4$$
$$x_2 =5(4)+2\ \ \text{ mod } 7 = 1$$

etc.

Comment: If the increment is 2, then why do we decrement the value of x0?

Comment: I don't understand why you think I'm subtracting anything from $x_0$. The $4$ came from the answer to the previous calculation. And in the future don't add new questions after you sumbit a question

Comment: Thanks I found out the remaining values. 
0,5,6